# Restrictive Access with System Administrator security role in CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am encountered with an insane problem when working in Dynamics CRM 2011 on-premises environment. Everything was working just fine 2 days back. There are two different CRM environment on my clients network (PreProd and Production).

I have System Administrator role on PreProd. The problem is that somehow I have restrictive access in CRM. Meaning, I am not able to create, update entity records. Create buttons are not even visible to my user for all entities!! When I open an entity form, Customize tab is not visible. In short, I have limited access even with System Administrator security role. I have never been in a problem like this before.

Any ideas that what could cause this? I don't have access to PreProd server so I can't troubleshoot this problem by myself. Any suggestions which I can convey them which might be helpful??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to recheck Access Mode field for mentioned user. Ensure that it has Read-Write value. If it is not - ask to update that field to Read-Write value.

Open user form in CRM and recheck following field:
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your point? What Access Mode field you are referring to? In the registry on PreProd Server?

Comment: Updated initial reply.

Comment: You are a genius and keen observer. Yes you are right I have Access mode `Read` and License Type 'Limited` set. These fields are read-only, who can update these values? I have also System Admin role shouldn't I have access to update this by myself?

Comment: In case you have Read Access Mode that means that you can only read records and not update and Sysadmin Role would not give you that possibility. I would suggest to find other Sysadmin with Read-Write Access Mode and ask to change your settings.